# Codenameone Media Loop or Listerner

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way I can loop a music track using `Media` ?
I don't even find a listener to get events if the media is complete.
Currently I am starting a timer task to check if the media is playing.
If its not I am playing it again.
Is there a better way to achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a media you can pass in a runnable that will accept a callback when the media completes. Currently we don't have a loop option and we dispose the media automatically on completion to avoid potential memory leaks. There is an RFE to add something like that in a future update.

Comment: What is the event when I will know that the media is complete ?

Comment: The Runnables run() method is invoked when the media is complete. When you create the media you can specify an onComplete runnable.

Comment: How exactly ? I am using: Media m = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/mp3");            m.play();

Comment: Use: MediaManager.createMedia(InputStream stream, String mimeType, Runnable onCompletion)